# what is this symbol ' ﾻ ' means?

Tags: terminology

What ㅋ or ﾻ means?
I know this is stupid question... and sorry for asking this...

actually, someone asked me  "I know what E 'reversed'. but what is 'reversed F' mean?"
Since I knew he is majoring math, I thought E is some kind of function or vector field, and have to reverse by axis or something.
but he just repeated "what is 'reversed F' mean? I don't even know whether it exists"
and I was confused. maybe he is dealing with some kind of existence problem. So I told him that it's confusing, and I think I need more information about the problem. then he just insulted me and left.

several minutes after, he came to me again and informed me that ﾻ is some kind of symbol, and left after cursing me. and realized 'reversed E' means 'there exist' sign ∃

So I had to know what 'ﾻ' means. I asked my friends majoring math and algebra professor. but I got no information. so this question is my last try.

Sorry to post this kind of question. I know this is not a proper question to this site.   But i really want to know what that symbol is.
thank you.

Comment: What context did you encounter this in? Are you sure it's not [korean](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%E3%85%8B)?

Comment: I know some people write $\mathscr{F}$ in a way that it might look like that

Comment: It's not korean. since this happened at korea, and he and I am korean.

Comment: It is a proper question all right, but the answer is negative. No, this thing does not seem to have any universally accepted meaning. It means nothing, unless you define it to mean something.

Comment: @IvanNeretin thanks.

Comment: All i know is that ㅋㅋㅋ means *lol*